# Does google look further then public_html

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, web-crawler, vps

We have a VPS and access with WHM/cPanel and we would like to know following:

Does Googles crawler see/crawle subdomains even if they aint pointing to the
 
public_html (and visa versa) and are not mentioned in Google Webmastertools?

Note: we have taken precautions through .htaccess and robots.txt and use `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">` but still found some in google Webmaster back-end which
we don't understand.
*(we have a test.ourdomain.com for developing new "stuff" and so on, therefore my question)*

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove external Urls in Blocked pages. Sometimes spiders will crawl the page if there is any genuine urls.
2. The simplest and most effective way to block private URLs from appearing is to store them in a password-protected directory on your site server. Googlebot and all other web crawlers are unable to access content in password-protected directories.

For more information https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93708